# Move icon to the right side of a nav-title

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, header

I want to create an app with a side menu and a title in the nav-title. On the right side of the nav-title i would place a icon.

This is my current code:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title align-title="center">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <img src="./img/MyIcon.ico" height="40px" width="auto">
    </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>
  ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

At the moment the title and the icon are both centered.

Is there a way to place the icon on the right side?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the image line out of `</icon-nav-title>` (which is centered), or float your image to the right with:

```
<img src="./img/MyIcon.ico" height="40px" width="auto" style="float:right">
```

You may want to try creating a CSS for this as well.